# Keep me in my retirement

Tags: meaning-in-context

While reading a book on Cicero, I encountered the following passage:

> I had to invent what is commonly called shorthand to cope with the flow, a system still used to record the deliberations of the senate, and for which I was recently awarded a modest pension. This, along with a few legacies and the kindness of friends, is sufficient to keep me in my retirement.

I want to ask about this phrase "keep in retirement". Does it mean he doesn't need to work and can thus remain retired, or does it mean he can sustain himself during retirement, or is it ambiguous?

Comment: It means he doesn't need to work in order to get money. The pension provides sufficient income.

Comment: The use of ***keep*** as a verb here derives from the noun sense [*Food, clothes, and other essentials for living*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/keep). Paraphrasing the cited example, it means *this is enough to **pay for** [those essentials] now that I'm retired from work and no longer earning a wage.*

Comment: Sufficient to pay for his *upkeep*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about keeping in retirement, as it is about *keeping someone*, in the sense of "(financially) sustaining someone".

Although not commonly used in that sense anymore, the expressions *kept man* and *kept woman* are still (occasionally?) used, meaning a man or a woman who is financially supported by someone else, usually a lover.

In this case, there is no such implication. He simply states that his pension, together with the other income, keeps him financially sustained during his retirement.